# Using tuples as inputs in functions

Tags: python, arrays, function, python-2.7, numpy

Suppose I define a function like so, where args should be a tuple that contains two elements, an example would be `(1,2)`:

```
def func(some_matrix,*args):
        return some_multiplication = some_matrix[0,first element of args] * some_matrix[0,second element of args]
```

How do I access the first and second elements of the tuple passed by the user in the body of the function? I also suppose that an example of calling a function would look something like: `func(A,(1,2))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that using list indexing or tuple indexing in this case

```
def acd(val, *vag):
    print '''Given Fixed value:\t{}
    Given Variable Tuple:\t{}
    First Var Value:\t{}
    Second Var value:\t{}
    Len of var:\t{}
    Len of first var element:\t{}
    '''.format(val, vag, vag[0][0], vag[0][1], len(vag), len(vag[0]))
acd(1, (3,4))
```

**Output:**

```
Given Fixed value:      1
Given Variable Tuple:   ((3, 4),)
First Var Value:        3
Second Var value:       4
Len of var:     1
Len of first var element:       2
```

Comment: This works. I was trying to make a loop inside the function run `len(args)` number of times, but for some reason I am getting inconclusive output for the `len(args)`. What is the correct way to find the number of entries in the tuple in the function?

Comment: `len(args)` is the number of objects in the `tuple` called `args`. If one of those objects, say, the first one, is a `tuple`, you can find its length with `len(args[0])`. It's exactly the same as any nested container.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal Ihave edited by answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal could you be more specific and I have not worked with numpy. SO a little more explanition would be nice :).

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal Based on that questions: Are you sure you need the `*` magic at all? Why not simply `def func(some_matrix, some_tupel):`?

Comment: @BlackJack how would I iterate through some_tupel in the body of the function? If that is possible, I think it would be much easier to do so

Comment: You iterate through a tuple in a function the same as you do outside of a function (e.g. in the interpreter).  Same way you iterate through a list.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal From the example I don't understand why you want to iterate over a tuple. The accepted answer doesn't and the code in the question doesn't call for this either. This answer needs `*vag` to be at least of length 1 and ignores any additional arguments to the function. It's somewhat a contradiction to use the magic for optional arguments (plural) to get exactly one, mandatory argument. That should be just a simple, non-starred argument. Why complicate things?

Comment: I would gladly omit complicating things. But I do not know how to define a function such that the second input is a tuple like so: def func(somethinf,(a,b)). And the above suggestion has worked.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal There is nothing special about a tuple as argument. Just `def func(something, xy):` and then call that function with a tuple as second argument. Within the function you can unpack the tuple (`a, b = xy`) or use indexing (`xy[0]` and `xy[1]`) to get the values in that tuple.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal In Python 2 you can even define the function _just the way you did_ in your last comment and use `a` and `b` within the function! This possibility is gone in Python 3.

Comment: Plus 1 to both comments. Thanks